# What does ## in stata mean?

Tags: stata

I came across the stata code that has `##` or `#` in it. I googled it but couldn't find . Please let me what does that mean in stata?

Comment: FWIW, the decision to use full factorial of the interactive variables has substantive implications for inferences & any "margins" one does post-estimation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can put a # between two variables to create an interaction–indicators for each combination of the categories of the variables. You can put ## instead to specify a full factorial of the variables—main effects for each variable and an interaction.

Check 
http://www.stata.com/capabilities/overview/factor-variables/